# Could not find executable in `PATH`. Please make sure Gauge is installed. even though its installed in windows and mac

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, intellij-plugin

Unable to start Gauge Intellij plugin.
Could not find executable in `PATH`. Please make sure Gauge is installed.
If Gauge is installed then set the Gauge executable path in settings -> tools -> gauge.

Comment: Did you try to re-install this plugin? I did it and fix the problem...